# dplyr sum by group by run ID

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

**My data**

```
is.over.sma ID.No   total.shares.months total.cost.months   total.shares.years  total.cost.years    RunID
1   79  0   0   0   0   7
1   80  0.79906924  833.3333333 0   0   7
1   81  0   0   0   0   7
1   82  0   0   0   0   7
1   83  0   0   0   0   7
1   84  0   0   0   0   7
1   85  0   0   0   0   7
1   86  0   0   0   0   7
1   87  0   0   0   0   7
1   88  0.56    700 0   0   7
1   89  0   0   0   0   7
1   90  0   0   0   0   7
1   91  0   0   0   0   7
1   92  0   0   0   0   7
1   93  0   0   0   0   7
1   94  0.78    900 0   0   8
1   95  0   0   0   0   8
1   96  0   0   0   0   8
1   97  0   0   0   0   8
1   98  0   0   0   0   8
1   99  0   0   0   0   8
1   100 0.751522595 833.3333333 0   0   8
1   101 0   0   0   0   8
1   102 0   0   0   0   8
```

The intention is to group by RunID. Then within each group sum total.shares.months columns and total.cost.months.

This is what I am trying:

```
# Dplyr to group by over.sma
output.sma <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(RunID = ifelse(is.over.sma == 1,data.table::rleid(is.over.sma),0)) %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  mutate(ID.No = ifelse(is.over.sma == 1,row_number(),0)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sum.shares.over.sma = ifelse(is.over.sma ==1,sum(total.shares.months),0)) %>%  # Divide total purchased by cost price for total share
  dplyr::mutate(sum.cost.over.sma = ifelse(is.over.sma ==1,sum(total.cost.months),0))
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-RunID)
```

Desired output for RunID 7 the sums should =

```
sum.shares.over.sma = 1.359
sum.cost.over.sma = 1533.33
```

For RunID 8:

```
sum.shares.over.sma = 1.531
sum.cost.over.sma = 1733.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your expected outcome, I think you could do the following. I called your data set `mydf`. You group the data by `RunID`. Then, you want to apply `sum()` to `total.shares.months` and `total.cost.months`, which you can do in `summarise_at()`.

```
group_by(mydf, RunID) %>%
summarise_at(vars(total.shares.months:total.cost.months),
             funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))
            )

  RunID total.shares.months total.cost.months
  <int>               <dbl>             <dbl>
1     7                1.36              1533
2     8                1.53              1733
```

Comment: Is there anyway to mutate, make a new column and store the sums at the end of each group, same index position as original?

Comment: @AndrewBannerman So you wanna have these values in two new columns? If so, you would see the same numbers of all rows in each group. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes - as from these, i can run more calculations on the new columns within each group

Comment: @AndrewBannerman OK. Then, try `group_by(mydf, RunID) %>%
mutate_at(vars(total.shares.months:total.cost.months), funs(new = sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))`. You will see `total.shares.months_new` and `total.cost.months_new` as new columns.

Comment: Cool beans! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is the accepted answer already and it's a perfect solution - just to show the `aggregate` version:

```
x <- merge( aggregate(total.shares.months + total.shares.years ~ RunID, data = mydf, sum ), 
            aggregate(total.cost.months + total.cost.years ~ RunID, data = mydf, sum ))
colnames( x )[2:3] <- c( "sum.shares.over.sma", "sum.cost.over.sma" )
x
  RunID sum.shares.over.sma sum.cost.over.sma
1     7            1.359069          1533.333
2     8            1.531523          1733.333
```